# How to get when a column becomes lower than another and when it becomes higher?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with a large data.table. Consider the following as an example:

```
#1st row is 
A <- c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8) 
#2nd row is
B <- c(9,9,7,6,5,6,7,7,8,8)
```

I need to know when B starts to be lower than A and when it becomes higher or equal to A.

What i want here is a Table like this:

```
begin end
  3    9
```

Comment: have a look at `rle(A>B)`

Comment: this is what i get `'x' must be a vector of an atomic type`

Comment: `A <- c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8); B <- c(9,9,7,6,5,6,7,7,8,8); rle(A>B)` I get a result (... from which you can construct your desired information). Did you used other data? I used the data from your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an idea using `sign`,

```
which(c(FALSE, diff(sign(A - B)) != 0))
#[1] 3 9
```

Comment: i get this using it in my true dataset `7  9 11 12 13 17 18 19 20 21 22 24 25 26 28 34 35 36` But i guess i have to take the first 2 values

Comment: That means you have more than one patterns.

Comment: Yes but i need to identify when it comes first

Comment: @Sotos `diff(A > B)` is a variant in the place of your `diff(...)`

Comment: @jogo I was between that and using `sign` but thought to use `sign` as It is not mentioned very often. But thanks for mentioning it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `rle()`

```
A <- c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8)
B <- c(9,9,7,6,5,6,7,7,8,8) 
l <- rle(A>B)$lengths
l[1] + 1        ## begin
l[1] + l[2] + 1 ## end
```

With `data.table` you can do:

```
library("data.table")
w <- which(rleid(A>B)==2)
min(w)     ## begin
max(w) + 1 ## end
```

or

```
library("data.table")
w <- which(rleid(A>B)==2)
w[1]          ## begin
tail(w,1) + 1 ## end
```

or

```
library("data.table")
r <- range(which(rleid(A>B)==2))
r[1]     ## begin
r[2] + 1 ## end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
begin = which(B<A)[1]
end = which(B>=A)[which(B>=A) > begin][1]
```